# How to display a listbox with the populated items on click of a menu item in XAML/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a context menu in my XAML file. When I click on this menu item, I want to display a listbox to the user with a list of data populated from a backend call. How can I achieve this? I am a novice in XAML/WPF.

Comment: 1. What all items have you tired? 2. What does this context menu attaches to? 3. Are you using MVVM pattern? 3. Where do you want to display the listbox? on the screen or on popup? 5. How long is the list of items? 6. Do you expect to load data on different thread? & many questions!!

Answer (score 0):

This would be your xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWpfApp.MyWindow"
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:MyWpfApp.MyCommandsNamespace"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyWpfApp.MyViewModelsNamespace"
    ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:MyItemClass}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyItemText}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
         <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static cmd:MyCommandsClass.MyCommand1}" Executed="ExecuteMyCommand" CanExecute="CanExecuteMyCommand"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Window.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="MyMenuItem1" 
              CommandTarget="{Binding}"
              Command="{x:Static cmd:MyCommandsClass.MyCommand1}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.ContextMenu>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and this would be your cs code:

```
    public MyWindow()
    {
        VM = new MyViewModelsNamespace.MyViewModel();
        this.DataContext = VM;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void ExecuteMyCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VM.MyList.Add(new MyItemClass{MyItemText="some text"});
    }
    public void CanExecuteMyCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (...) e.CanExecute = false;
        else e.CanExecute = true;
    }
```

where MyViewModel is something like:

```
    public class MyViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        //MyList Observable Collection
        private ObservableCollection<MyItemClass> _myList = new ObservableCollection<MyItemClass>();
        public ObservableCollection<MyItemClass> MyList { get { return _myList; } }
    }
```

and MyItemClass is something like:

```
    public class MyItemClass : DependencyObject
    {
        //MyItemText Dependency Property
        public string MyItemText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MyItemTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyItemTextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyItemText", typeof(string), typeof(MyItemClass), new UIPropertyMetadata("---"));
    }
```

I forgot to mention command:

```
public static class MyCommandsClass
{
    public static RoutedCommand MyCommand1 = new RoutedCommand();
}
```

Comment: hope this will help. by the way I forgot to mention command declaration. I've added it to the answer.